# WordPress: Inserting diagonal splash banner into OnePress Hero section

Tags: html, wordpress, css, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a client for whom I have set up a website with WordPress (as requested), using the OnePress free theme. The client has now requested an angled splash sign to be aligned left within the rotating Hero section - I have provided a photoshop mockup of his request.[Splash mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20uYf.jpg)  I am not sure if I could reasonably do this within the constraints of the theme though, and if I could, whether or not it would be responsive. Can anyone help with this? Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything? ([ask])

Comment: checkout this CSS only solution: https://codepen.io/alexerlandsson/pen/NqXWwX

Comment: Hi @ochi, thanks for your input. I've sat and fiddled with this thing for an hour, and to my frustration, I can only code within the div called "hero__content". So no matter what styling I apply to a new div within this existing div, it will stay within the bounds of it - as per the following link. I could maybe force it out of bounds with margins, but I have no idea how that would behave on mobile. What I need, is to be able to place a new div inside "hero-slideshow-wrapper" and style that as the banner - but I can't do that. :(
https://imgur.com/O3BBQJE

Comment: Please include code to your question.... (a [mcve]) - it's very hard to work from only your image...